# Getting output as "Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'" in flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I am trying get sum of a column in sqlite table using Bloc pattern.

**debt_bloc.dart**

```
getTotalAmount() async {
    return await _debtRepository.getTotalAmt();
  }
```

**debt_dao.dart**

```
 Future<int> getTotalAmount() async {
    final db = await dbProvider.database;

    var result = await db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM $debtDetailsTable");
    int value = result[0]["SUM(amount)"];
    return value;
  }
```

**debt_repositary.dart**

```
Future getTotalAmount() => debtDao.getTotalAmount();
```

When i try to print like below

```
var total;
   @override
    void initState () {
      super.initState();
     _asyncMethod();
    }

    _asyncMethod() async {
      var t = await debtBloc.getTotalAmount();
      setState(() {
        total = t;
      });
    }

    print(total);
```

Output not updating when add new data. But if go back to home screen and come to respective screen value is updating.

Please guide me in right way. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Await on your method first before printing it.

```
var total = await debtBloc.getTotalAmount(); // await here
print(total); // should now print some int value
```

Comment: Now that is solved but output value is "null". I am new to flutter dn't know how null is coming. Trying to fix it, If you have any idea about it, help me out.

Comment: While tried to print in debt_dao.dart.  var result = await db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM $debtDetailsTable");  print(result); output comes correct.

Comment: What `int value = result[0]["SUM(amount)"];` prints?

Comment: It prints sum of amount column value. Ex. 30000

Comment: @Nagaraj I understand what it should print but can you tell me what exactly the current value prints.

Comment: It prints "null". One more thing whenever i add new entry value should updated in widget view.

Comment: What does your `var result` prints?

Comment: I have done changes in code it works now but its not working while adding new data to database. changed above code also